# Alternative characterization of total variation of $L^1$ functions

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, bounded-variation, total-variation

This is about exercise 3.3 from Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*. I struggled with this for some time.

Let $\Omega$ be an open set and $u \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. Show that the totalvariation $V(u, \cdot)$ is the least Borel measure $\mu$ s.t.

$$
\int_K \frac{|u(x+y) - u(x)|}{|y|}\mathrm{d}x \leq \mu\big(\{x \in \Omega: \text{dist}(x,K) < |y|\}\big).
$$

for any compact set $K \subset \Omega$ and any $y \in \mathbb{R}^N\setminus \{0\}$ such that $|y| < \text{dist}(K, \partial \Omega)$.

Here the total variation is defined on open sets $A$ like usual by

$$ V(u,A) := \sup\left\{ \int_A u(x)\text{div}\phi(x) \mathrm{d}x: \phi \in C^1_c(A), \left\lVert\phi\right\rVert_\infty \leq 1\right\}.$$

Does anyone have an idea? Particular the part about that the total variation is the least Borel measure that has this property has me kind of stumbled.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hmmm ... what I tried is looking why it should work for $C^\infty$ functions. You get relatively fast that their TV has to fulfill this inequality. By approximation this holds for $BV$ functions. I am not sure why this has to hold for arbitrary $L^1_{loc}$ tbh. 
Why this is the least Borelmeasure is the part which confuses me the most .. maybe one can somehow multiply the term in the integral with a suitable test function. But I do not get how to set this up correctly.

Comment: Are you able to prove this when $d = 1$?  I have a feeling the general case can be treated using slicing (i.e. Section 3.11 of the book you referenced).  What I have in mind is to show that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\|Du\|$ and $\frac{d\mu}{d\|Du\|} \geq 1$ $\|Du\|$-a.e.